# How to change the color that is above the Action Bar by button?

Tags: java, android

I have a button that changes only Action Bar colour. I want to change the colour that is above Action Bar by clicking the button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you want to change statusbar color?

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();

window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```